# Why is "new String();" a statement but "new int[0];" not?

Tags: java, syntax

I just randomly tried seeing if `new String();` would compile and it did (because according to Oracle's Java documentation on "Expressions, Statements, and Blocks", one of the valid statement types is "object creation"),

However, `new int[0];` is giving me a "not a statement" error.

What's wrong with this? Aren't I creating an array object with `new int[0]`?

EDIT:

To clarify this question, the following code:

```
class Test {
    void foo() {
        new int[0];
        new String();
    }
}
```

causes a compiler error on `new int[0];`, whereas `new String();` on its own *is* fine. Why is one not acceptable and the other one is fine?

Comment: That's not the correct syntax in Java for what you are wanting to do

Comment: Please show *complete* examples - i.e., enough code to test compiling those lines.

Comment: The syntax is more like: `int[] intArray = new int[]{0};`

Comment: To the closers: This needs neither details nor clarity; I know the question sounds strange but it is on point. Specifically, `class X { void foo() { new int[0]; }}` is a compile error, whereas `void foo() { new String(); }}` is not. I shall provide an answer once it is unclosed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - it's quite easy. Try compiling a class where the entire body of `main()` is `new String();` and then try with the body being `new int[0];`.  Do you not find that slightly interesting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is a somewhat overengineered spec.

The idea behind expressions not being valid statements is that they accomplish nothing whatsoever. `5 + 2;` does nothing on its own. You must assign it to something, or pass it to something, otherwise why write it?

There are exceptions, however: Expressions which, on their own, will (or possibly will) have side effects. For example, whilst  this is illegal:

```
void foo(int a) {
    a + 1;
}
```

This is not:

```
void foo(int a) {
    a++;
}
```

That is because, on its own, `a++` is not completely useless, it actually changes things (a is modified by doing this). Effectively, 'ignoring the value' (you do nothing with `a + 1` in that first snippet) is acceptable if the act of producing the value on its own causes other stuff to happen: After all, maybe that is what you were after all along.

For that reason, invoking methods is also a legit expressionstatement, and in fact it is quite common that you invoke methods (even ones that don't return `void`), ignoring the return value. For void methods it's the only legal way to invoke them, even.

Constructors are technically methods and can have side effects. It is extremely unlikely, and quite bad code style, if this method:

```
void doStuff() {
    new Something();
}
```

is 'sensible' code, but it *could* in theory be written, bad as it may be: The constructor of the `Something` class may do something useful and perhaps that's all you want to do here: Make that constructor run, do the useful thing, and then take the created object and immediately toss it in the garbage. Weird, but, okay. You're the programmer.

Contrast with:

```
new Something[10];
```

This is different: The compiler **knows** what the array 'constructor' does. And what it does is **nothing useful** - it creates an object and returns a reference to the object, and that is *all* that happens. If you then instantly toss the reference in the garbage, then the entire operation was a complete waste of time, and surely you did not intend to do nothing useful with such a bizarre statement, so the compiler designers thought it best to just straight up disallow you from writing it.

This 'oh dear that code makes no sense therefore I shall not compile it' is *very* limited and mostly an obsolete aspect of the original compiler spec; it's never been updated and this is not a good way to trust that code is sensible; there's all sorts of linter tools out there that go vastly further in finding you code that just cannot be right, so if you care about that sort of thing, invest in learning those.

Nevertheless, the java 1.0 spec had this stuff baked in and there is no particularly good reason to drop this aspect of the java spec, therefore, it remains, and constructing a new array is not a valid ExpressionStatement.

As [JLS §14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-ExpressionStatement) states, specifically, a **`ClassInstanceCreationExpression`** is in the list of valid expressionstatements. Click that word to link to the definition of `ClassInstanceCreationExpression` and you'll find that it specifically refers to invoking constructors, and **not** to array construction.

Thus, the JLS is specific and **requires** this behaviour. javac is simply following the spec.